# How do I change EditTexts when clicking next?

Tags: java, android

I have an EditText box that appears and the hint in it is actually a question that needs to be answered.  Once the user enters the value and hits next, how can I make a different EditText box take the originals place.  I want to do this so there is a new hint(question) and I can manipulate that input differently than with the first input.

In my example, my first EditText is `enter_one` and I want it to change to `enter_two` after the `next_button` is clicked.

Thank you for your help!

```
final EditText getInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enter_key_one);
Button clickButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
clickButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String newValue = getInput.getText().toString().trim();
        int input = Integer.parseInt(newValue);
        System.out.println("Your value is " +input);
    }
});
```

Comment: Use the same box...  catch the various inputs to different vars...   i think that is less work....   never tried it though so...

Comment: You can do it by one edittext too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two edit text in XML layout, and align both in same position, one over another. Then declare the `android:visibility="gone"` for  edittext `enter_two`.

Then onClick of next should be:

```
final EditText getInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enter_key_one);

final EditText getInput_two = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enter_key_two);
Button clickButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
clickButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String newValue = getInput.getText().toString().trim();
        int input = Integer.parseInt(newValue);
        System.out.println("Your value is " +input);

getInput_two.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
getInput.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, I've been searching for the wrong thing this whole time.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can just change the hint and clear the `EditText` :

```
final EditText getInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enter_key_one);
Button clickButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
clickButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        getInput.setHint(newQuestion);
        getInput.setText("");
    }
});
```

Comment: My first thought exactly

Comment: Thanks for this, it's a very useful tip just not exactly what I was looking for.